# How do I capture the email validation timing in an enrollment form?

Tags: performance

I want to check how long it will take a user to do the enrollment of a web application. Is there any tool to capture the timing? Also need to run multiple user and capture the submission timing. I want to ensure that how long it will take user email to validate.

Pls suggest any ideas.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm afraid your question in this form is pretty vauge, so it needs some rework before we can help you. Could you please clarify in what Programming language would you focus on? 
What have you already tried? 
Hope this helps!

Comment: My question is In an enrollment form how long an API will take to validate the email field i.e the user entered email address is valid one or not. Is there any tool to check the performance?

Comment: You need to give more details, as your question is too broad, and not specific to programming.